# Easy topology proofs... are they correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ Show the following:

> The set $A^{\circ}$ of interior points of $A$ is open.

Proof. A point $a$ is an interior point of $A^{\circ}$ if there exists a neighborhood $B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset A^{\circ}.$ But $A^{\circ} \subset A$ so that $B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset A,$ and hence $a \in A^{\circ}.$ Thus $A^{\circ}$ contains all of its interior points, and so is open. $\Box$

> $(b)$ if $U \subseteq A$ is another set and $U$ is open, then $U \subseteq A^{\circ};$

Proof. Suppose that $u \in U.$ Since $U$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon} (u) \subset U \subset A,$ which implies that every $u$ is an interior point of $A,$ and hence $U \subset A^{\circ}. \Box$

> $(c)$ the set $A^{\circ}$ equals the union over all open sets $U_i$ which are contained in $A,$ i.e., if $U_i \subset A$ is an open set, then $$A^{\circ} =  \bigcup_{i \in \Omega}  U_i = \bigcup_{U \subseteq A, \hspace{0.4mm} U \text{ open } } U;$$

Proof. Let $a \in A^{\circ}.$ Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset A.$ So $a \in B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset U^\prime = \bigcup_{i \in \Omega}  U_i,$ meaning that $A^{\circ} \subset U^\prime.$ Now assume that $a \in U^\prime.$ Then $a \in U_i$ for some $i \in \Omega.$ Since $U_i$ is open, it follows that $a$ is an interior point of $U_i.$ Thus there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset U_i \subset A,$ and so $a \in A^{\circ}.$ Thus $U^\prime \subset A^{\circ},$ and since $U^\prime \supset A^{\circ},$ it follows that $A^{\circ} = U^\prime.  \Box$

> $(d)$ $A^{\circ}$ is the largest open set contained in $A.$

Proof. Let $B$ be an open subset of $A$ such that $A^{\circ} \subset B \subset U^\prime.$ We know that $A^{\circ} = U',$ which implies that $B = A^{\circ}.$ Thus $A^{\circ}$ is the largest open set contained in $A. \Box$

$\textbf{Question:}$ Are these correct and did I include enough detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) you have the definition of open backwards.  A set A is open if every point of A is an interior point; not the other way.  *All* sets  contain all their interior points because interior points are always points of the set.

Instead let $a$ be any point of $A^{\circ}$. Show it is an interior point of $A^{\circ}$ and thus all points of $A^{\circ}$ are interior points so they are open.

Hint: if $a \in A^{\circ}$  then it is an interior of A so there is a neighbor hood around a entirely in A. Prove that neighborhood is also entirely in $A^{\circ}$.

b) c) and d) are good.  d) is particularly nice.

but c) You don't need to prove $A^{\circ} \subset U'$.  By a) you know that $A^{\circ} *is* an open subset of A so it *is* one of the U.  The rest is good.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help